# Php 7.4 version and unable to access user authorization page

Tags: php

I am using php 7.4.  I have a php page called auth1.  It requires a username and Password, which in the
past took me into auth3.  I started receiving a deprecated error when I was on php 5.4 so I upgraded to
7.4.  Now I get the error messages below.  Any ideas.  Could it be my mysql not compatible

`Warning: Use of undefined constant user - assumed 'user' (this will throw an Error in a future version of  PHP) in /home/utm/public_html/auth3.php on line 5`

`Warning: Use of undefined constant password - assumed 'password' (this will throw an Error in a future  version of PHP) in /home/utm/public_html/auth3.php on line 5`

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in  /home/utm/public_html/auth3.php:19 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in  /home/utm/public_html/auth3.php on line 19`

Comment: the legacy mysql functions has been removed. You'll need to update your code to the new APIs. The deprecated notice was already pointing to that earlier when you saw.

Comment: does that mean point to mysqli  ??

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stackoverflow

your first and second lines are not Uncaught error and don't break your php processes

but about your last line it tell you that mysql_connect doesn't exists

because mysql extension and all of mysql_* functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and has been removed as of PHP 7 to up

as the [itachi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1164513/itachi) said, and you said an example (mysqli) you should use a new extension between 3 following ways:

1. MySQLI reference functions [Check they here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysqli.php)
2. MySQLI OOP extension [Check they here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php)
3. PDO Extension [Check they here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

---

Also you can see this references for install your needs:

[PDO Installation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setup.php)

[MySQLI Installation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.setup.php)

---

and about your 1st and 2nd lines you could put your codes to let us check, know and solve your problem